# Find Biggest Row By Two Values LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
ID   Value
20   200
20   300
10   100
10   050
```

I need to get the Biggest ID which has the biggest value, and then store target ID and its value. In above example the output should be (ID=20,Value=300). I know I can use Max but it seems I can not use && to check two value.

Comment: Use `&&`. How? [Showing your efforts is relevant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305399/861716).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to use `OrderBy`:

```
var biggestByIdAndValue = values.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                                .ThenByDescending(x => x.Value)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on collection type you use and the size of the collection it might be better to use approach like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var fooList = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo { Id = 20, Value = 200 },
            new Foo { Id = 20, Value = 300 },
            new Foo { Id = 10, Value = 100 },
            new Foo { Id = 10, Value = 050 }
        };

        var maxId = fooList.Max(f => f.Id);
        var maxValue = fooList.Where(f => f.Id == maxId).Max(f => f.Value);

        Console.WriteLine("Max Id = {0}", maxId);
        Console.WriteLine("Max value = {0}", maxValue);
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But @2kay s method would work just fine for demonstration purposes on any collection of decent size.